# count function only outputing 1 python

Tags: python, printing, return

Using return only gives me the number 1, even though its found 796 times using a print statement, just wondering what I'm doing wrong whether its indentation errors or something like that.

```py
def findSubstringInTweets(userName, tweetFile, substring):
    
    import csv
    # open file
    myFile = open(tweetFile,"r")
    # create csv reader
    csvReader = csv.reader(myFile)
    # skip header
    next(csvReader)
    variableCounter = 0
    for line in myFile: # iterate through each line
        lineParts = line.split(",")  # split the line by the comma
        if ((lineParts[0]) == userName):
            for char in lineParts[1]:
                if char == substring:
                    variableCounter += 1
                    **return** (substring+" was found "+str(variableCounter)+" times in tweets written by "+userName)
```

example: findSubstringInTweets("SenatorHarkin", "DemocratTweets-Fall2020.csv", '@')

```
'@ was found 1 times in tweets written by SenatorHarkin'
```

but when I use print instead of return it will count all the way up to a certain number and then print:

```
...
@ was found 795 times in tweets written by SenatorHarkin
@ was found 796 times in tweets written by SenatorHarkin
```

Comment: `return` causes the function to exit immediately.  So your function will exit as soon as it finds one match.

Comment: Move the `return` statement to the end of the function, after all the loops have finished.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments have noted, the `return` statement causes your loops to exit once that condition is met.

You can move the `return` statement outside your loops like below, to return the target output once all your loops have completed:

```
import csv
# open file
myFile = open(tweetFile,"r")
# create csv reader
csvReader = csv.reader(myFile)
# skip header
next(csvReader)
variableCounter = 0
for line in myFile: # iterate through each line
    lineParts = line.split(",")  # split the line by the comma
    if ((lineParts[0]) == userName):
        for char in lineParts[1]:
            if char == substring:
                variableCounter += 1
# Move our return statement outside our for loops - That way, after all our loops have processed, we return our value                
return(substring+" was found "+str(variableCounter)+" times in tweets written by "+userName)
```